# Loading Data from sql table to spark dataframe in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

I'm new to dbricks and I'm learning it. I am trying to load a SQL table into a dataframe. I am following the official documentation from Microsoft.

But I am getting this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

My notebook block:

```
connectionProperties = {
  "Driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://removed.database.windows.net"
database_name = "demo"
url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"

table_name = "Production.Data"
username = "removed"
password = "dummy"
try:
    Dataframe = spark.read \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password).load()
except ValueError as error :
    print("Connector write failed", error)
```

Error :

[image]

Comment: Do you have this com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark jar installed on databricks cluster where you are running this code?

Answer (score 0):

> **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**

This error mainly happens because of ***package missing***, please install below package.

[image: Ref1]

> **Loading Data from SQL table to spark dataframe**

Please follow below repro it has a detailed information about how to connect Azure SQL to Databricks.

> **PySpark**

**Updated code:**

```
jdbcHostname = "xxxx.database.windows.net"
jdbcDatabase = "Databasename"
jdbcPort = "1433"
username = "sql Username"
password = "xxxxx"
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
conProp = {
    
   "user" : username,
   "password" : password,
   "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
 }

def1 = "(Select * from Table_name where Table_ID = 1) Table_ID "
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=def1, properties=conProp)
display(df)
```

**Output**:

[image: Ref3]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases

https://www.sqlshack.com/load-data-into-azure-sql-database-from-azure-databricks/

Comment: Hey , Yes i saw this , but we dont use scala as of now , so im trying this is spark .

Comment: hi @gahaninadhb, just updated the code, can you please check?

Comment: Hey @gahaninadh b, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot.  [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers "https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers")